# Url routing from HTML page Like with ul and Li?

Tags: asp.net

Hello
  i am trying to impelement Url routing in asp.net 4.0. it works fine with i have button click event.
But how to navigate from href or li?
i have used the code

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomRouteTable(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void CustomRouteTable(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Movie", "Movies", "~/Default.aspx"); 
    routes.MapPageRoute("English", "Movie/English","~/Hollywood/Hollywood.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Tamil", "Movie/Tamil", "~/Tamil/Tamil.aspx");
}
```

and in HTML side i wrote:

```
<ul class="MasterMenu">
    <li><a href="Movie">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="English">Hollywood</a></li>
    <li><a href="Movie/Tamil">Tamil</a></li>
</ul>
```

but i end up in error.
How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i could solve it.

```
<ul class="MasterMenu">
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Movies">Home</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Movie/English">Hollywood</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Movie/Tamil">Tamil</a></li>

                                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the first link be Movies instead of Movie?

You should be able to easily resolve the issue by including the complete path, including the domain. If you really prefer a relative path, then we need to talk which directory this page is in, just like you would for any other relative path.